# Access data inside nested proto field

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

First off, sorry if the title is poorly worded. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing here as it's my first time working with protobuf.

I have the following output from decoding a .bin file using protoc

```
1: 1540
2: "test"
3: 186
4: 10041
5: "test2"
11: 1
12: 1
13: 1
14: 1
15: 1
16: 1
17: 1
18: 1
19: 1
101 {
  1 {
    1: 1540
    2: 379
    3: 60
    4: 0
    5: 1553862415000
  }
}
```

I'm making a proto file with the following message

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Profile {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  required int32 rank = 3;
  required string description = 5;
  required string test = 101;
}
```

How do I setup the message so I can access data inside `101` since it has nested fields inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the decoded message, is looks like it was really generated from something like

```
message Profile {
  (...)
  required Level2 test = 101;
}

message Level2 {
  optional Level3 nested = 1;
}

message Level3 {
  optional int32 field1 = 1;
  optional int32 field2 = 2;
  optional int32 field3 = 3;
  optional int32 field4 = 4;
  optional int32 field5 = 5;
}
```

Of course, it's hard to say if the `int32` type is correct, or if any of those fields should be repeated.

You can change the message definition to something like the above, if you want to access those fields.

If you don't want to parse the field (i.e. return it as simply its serialized representation, you can just make it be typed as `bytes`:

```proto
message Profile {
  (...)
  required bytes test = 101;
}
```